# How to secure access to the azure application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have created an azure application which I use to sync user data using graph API. I am able to sync the data. However, I have a security concern. I am using certificate based authentication for the graph api to access data. However, if anyone has access to the certificate, he can access the graph API to sync the data.

1. **Is there anyway, we can limit the application access using Graph API?**
2. **Can we limit the access to certain IP ranges?**

Answer (score 0):

1. No
2. You can use [Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview) to block access to users using [ip addresses ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-policy-location) but not to service principals in case you're authenticating as an application.